# What does 'virus prototype strain' mean?

Tags: terminology, virology

Does the term 'prototype virus strain' mean the first virus isolated and without mutations?

Answer (score 4):

A prototype virus may or may not be the first isolated virus of a group. It's essentially the same as a "reference" virus -- in fact, the [International Committee on Taxonomy of Viruses
(ICTV)](https://talk.ictvonline.org/information/) uses the terms interchangeably, as in the  [Hepeviridae Study Group](https://talk.ictvonline.org/ictv_wikis/hepeviridae/w/sg_hepe) which has a column entitled "Prototype/Reference Strain".

In many cases the reference virus *is* the first isolate, but it isn't necessarily the case. The ICTV is the official body that determines reference strains, and they may choose a different virus as the reference/prototype. For example the first isolate may turn out to be unusual or an outlier in same way, so that a more typical strain may be chosen as a reference or prototype (I don't know offhand of examples of this though).

"Prototype" is often used in a broader sense as well, where a group of viruses can act as prototypes for a still broader group.  For example, ["The genomic structure of Pencillium chrysogenum virus (PcV), the prototype of the genus Chrysovirus ... "](https://talk.ictvonline.org/cfs-filesystemfile/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/13-51-00-00-00-00-44-43/2012.004aF.A.v3.Chrysovirus_2D00_5sp.pdf) (pdf link) uses "prototype" to refer to all the viruses in the Pencillium chrysogenum group, as compared to the broader genus.

Answer (score 1):

virus strain:

> Different lines or isolates of the same virus (e.g., from different geographical location or patients)

prototype:

> the first example of something, such as a machine or other industrial product, from which all later forms are developed

I think prototype of virus strain is first isolated virus of that strain.

Refferences

---

Principles of Molecular Virology fourth edition; Alan J. Cann; page 64.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_(biology)
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prototype